# Recover file MySQL .IBD

Tags: mysql

had a problem with a database on a machine that needed to be formatted, and I backed up the MySQL Server folder yesterday containing the .IDB and .FRM data regarding the DB structure and data.

When replacing files of the same structure on another machine and attempting to perform a query, the database is corrupted. After a bit of research I read that after version 5.5 MySQL creates a reference so it does not exchange this data.

How could I recover this data? Is there any other tool for me to read the file?

Comment: Were both versions the same?

Comment: You did need `ibdata1`, did you include it?  If not, do you have the `CREATE TABLEs` for each table?